# R Makevars file not correctly overriding g++

Tags: c++, r, rstudio

I'm trying to install the R package 'lubridate' on Centos 6.  Because lubridate requires a more recent version of g++ than the standard compiler on Centos 6 I downloaded and compiled version gcc 4.9 (from what I've been reading, lubridate requires >v4.8)

I've then added the lines:

```
CXX=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++
CC=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/gcc -std=gnu99
```

to the ~/.R/Makevars file, to try and force it to use the newer compiler, but when I try installing lubridate I get this error:

```
> install.packages("lubridate")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lubridate_1.7.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 450988 bytes (440 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 440 KB

* installing *source* package ‘lubridate’ ...
** package ‘lubridate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -fpic  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -c datetime.c -o datetime.o
/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -fpic  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -c period.c -o period.o
/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -fpic  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -c tparse.c -o tparse.o
tparse.c: In function ‘C_parse_dt’:
tparse.c:338:26: warning: ‘oMIN’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         INTEGER(oMIN)[i] = M;
                          ^
tparse.c:337:27: warning: ‘oHOUR’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         INTEGER(oHOUR)[i] = H;
                           ^
tparse.c:336:26: warning: ‘oDAY’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         INTEGER(oDAY)[i] = d;
                          ^
tparse.c:335:28: warning: ‘oMONTH’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         INTEGER(oMONTH)[i] = m - 1;
                            ^
tparse.c:334:27: warning: ‘oYEAR’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         INTEGER(oYEAR)[i] = y - 1900;
                           ^
g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c update.cpp -o update.o
In file included from ./cctz/include/civil_time.h:18,
                 from update.cpp:3:
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:37: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘year_t’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:37: error: ‘year_t’ has not been declared
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:37: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:37: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:41: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘diff_t’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:41: error: ‘diff_t’ has not been declared
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:41: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:41: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:46: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘month_t’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:46: error: ‘month_t’ has not been declared
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:46: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:47: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘day_t’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:47: error: ‘day_t’ has not been declared
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:47: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:48: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘hour_t’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:48: error: ‘hour_t’ has not been declared
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:48: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:48: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:49: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘minute_t’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:49: error: ‘minute_t’ has not been declared
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:49: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:49: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:50: error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘second_t’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:50: error: ‘second_t’ has not been declared
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:50: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:50: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=��� token
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:54: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘year’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:78: error: ‘cctz::detail::impl::is_leap_year’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:78: error: ‘year_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:78: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:81: error: ‘cctz::detail::impl::year_index’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:81: error: ‘year_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:81: error: ‘month_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:81: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:81: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:84: error: ‘cctz::detail::impl::days_per_century’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:84: error: ‘year_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:84: error: ‘month_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:84: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:84: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:88: error: ‘cctz::detail::impl::days_per_4years’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:88: error: ‘year_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:88: error: ‘month_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:88: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:88: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:92: error: ‘cctz::detail::impl::days_per_year’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:92: error: ‘year_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:92: error: ‘month_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:92: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:92: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:95: error: ‘cctz::detail::impl::days_per_month’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:95: error: ‘year_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:95: error: ‘month_t’ was not declared in this scope
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:95: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
./cctz/include/civil_time_detail.h:95: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘noexcept’
update.cpp:452: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
update.cpp:452: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
update.cpp:452: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
make: *** [update.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lubridate’
* removing ‘/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/lubridate’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lubridate’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpRwMbsZ/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

What is interesting is that it looks like it is trying to correctly use the right gcc:

```
/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -fpic  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -c datetime.c -o datetime.o
```

but not the right g++ (not listing the full path I defined in the ~/.R/Makevars file):

```
g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
```

If I change the lines in the ~/.R/Makevars file to instead be:

```
CXX=g++
CC=gcc
```

Then it looks like both executables become the normal system ones:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
gcc -I/opt/R/R-3.3.3/include -DNDEBUG -I. -I./cctz/include/ -I./cctz/src/ -I/usr/local/include -I"/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/Rcpp/include"  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -fpic  -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -std=gnu99 -fopenmp -c datetime.c -o datetime.o
```

Is there another file that is taking priority over my defined g++ location in the ~/.R/Makevars file somewhere?  The real question is how do I get R to use /opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++ here?

Comment: Have you tried setting `CXX11=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++`?

Comment: Just tried, still the same results.  However that is interesting, is there a different CXX for -std=c++0x?

Comment: I just saw the latest `lubridate` has `CXX_STD = CXX11`. There is a `CXX98` as well

Comment: Tried setting: `CXX=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++
CC=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/gcc -std=gnu99
CXX11STD=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++
CXX11=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++
CXX98=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++
CXX14=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++
CXX17=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++` (because i don't really know what I'm doing here) but none of them change which g++ is being used :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I needed to set `CXX1X=/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/bin/g++` in the ~/.R/Makevars file, after that the lubridate package used the intended g++, and successfully compiled.  Unfortunately, that hasn't completely solved my problem as R can't load the library:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/lubridate/libs/lubridate.so':
  /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/lubridate/libs/lubridate.so)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/lubridate’
```

Looks like R is using the `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`, instead of (probably?) using `/opt/gcc_4.9.1/rtf/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`. But it does resolve the question I was asking here.  If I can figure out how to get it to load, I'll post back here, in case anyone else is trying to do the same thing. Thanks to RolandASc for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Any word on fixing this error: unable to load shared object '/opt/R/R-3.3.3/library/lubridate/libs/lubridate.so'?  I'm getting the same error